# Create 2 / Roomba

Tags: ros, roomba, create2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm new in ROS forum.
My name is Thomas and I come from Italy.
I tried to buy the Irobot Create 2, but as you probabily know, in Europe is too difficult to purchase it.
Does someone know which is the best substitute of Create 2?
Which roomba?

Thank you
Thomas

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243379/create-2-/-roomba/) by [ThomasPittin](https://answers.ros.org/users/27942/thomaspittin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-09-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Thomas, welcome!

I believe Roomba 600 series robots are the closest match to Create 2.

Just so you know, [create_autonomy](https://github.com/AutonomyLab/create_autonomy) (which I am currently developing) supports most Roomba models :)

---

Originally posted by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) with karma: 1870 on 2016-09-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0